# Mongodb query to find all the keys by its values

Tags: java, mongodb, object, key

I new to mongodb. I have a doc which is look like
[image]

So I want to fire a query for object "users" which gives me all the key names who values is true.

Please answer in java

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation pipeline in `3.4.4` version.

Change the `users` embedded document into array of key value pairs using `$objectToArray` followed by `$filter + $map` to extract the keys for matching value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            keys: {
                $map: {
                    input: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$users"},
                            as: "resultf",
                            cond: {
                                $eq: ["$$resultf.v", true]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    as: "resultm",
                    in: "$$resultm.k"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you all the users keys whose value is true in array format -

```
db.collectionName.find({},{users:1}).map(function(myDoc){
  var names = [];
  for (var key in myDoc.users) {
    if(myDoc.users[key]){
      names.push(key);
    }
  }
  return names;
});
```

Comment: can you change your answer from js to java